# Assign another value to a string variable

Tags: javascript

sorry if the question was asked before and I guess it's quite simple, but I can't figure it out: how can I reassign the value of a variable? I need the result of the code below to be "Hello Ana" and "Hello Maria", but it doesn't recognize the second assignment, I get "Hello Ana" twice. Thanks! 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlEbr.png)

```
var name = "Ana";
var greeting = "Hello " + name;
console.log(greeting);
name = "Maria";
console.log(greeting);
```

Comment: You need to re-evaluate `greeting = "Hello " + name`, or extract a function that does that. `greeting` is a totally separate string, you should not expect it to change because the strings you build it from do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `greeting` to contain the *current* value of the `name` variable, you have to change it to a function:

```js
var name = "Ana";
var greeting = () => "Hello " + name;
console.log(greeting());
name = "Maria";
console.log(greeting());
```